# (click) event not working Typescript while append any data in ANGULAR 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, fullcalendar, angular2-template

I have been trying to get click event from .ts, actually I'm working in full calendar in this i have append html code, all I'm trying to get click event function and I don't now how to catch the function.

```
             viewRender: function (view, element) {
              // element.find('.fc-day-header').html('ZDAAD');
              const d = '<div class= "col-sm-12"><input type="checkbox" id="click" class="appointment-margin-checkbox" (click)='myEvent()'/></div>';
              element.find('.fc-axis:first').html(d);
            },
myEvent( ){ alert() } // here i need the checkbox is checked or not
```

Please help out

Comment: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: I don't think DomSanitizer can help me in this situation. I have tried nop, I didn't got anything.

Comment: who ever kept -1 can they give answer to me

Comment: How about not using inline event?

Answer (score 0):

> Correct me if i'm wrong.

Don't make the event to inline, so your code should look like:

```
viewRender: function(view, element) {
  // element.find('.fc-day-header').html('ZDAAD');
  const d = '<div class= "col-sm-12" id="my-id"><input type="checkbox" id="click" class="appointment-margin-checkbox"/></div>';
  element.find('.fc-axis:first').html(d);
  element.find('#my-id')[0].onclick = this.myEvent;
}
myEvent() {
  alert('it works')
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have done according to u . Alert is not working @Radonirina

Comment: I don't know if this is the to make an event an angular
with jQuery . Can you check if the element has method on click?

Comment: I have tied all the way but I'm unable to get solution for this.